# How to get the rest of the list from a subset of it

Tags: python, arrays

`a` and `b` are lists of numbers and there are duplicates. `b` is a subset of `a`.

For example:

```py
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
b = [1, 1, 2]
```

I'm working on a function to get the rest of `a` after deleting the numbers in `b`:

```
>>> func(a, b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

I know it can be achived by enumerating through the list, but is there an easier way to get the result?

Comment: As far as we can tell you _aren't_ slicing anything (it wouldn't really make sense to do so). If you know how it can be achieved, where's your implementation?

Comment: If func() returns a list simply save it to a new or existing variable, if it alters an existing variable you dont have to do anything?

Comment: What's wrong with `set(a)` (avoiding slicing)?

Comment: after getting a combination by itertools, I also want to get the rest of it

Answer (score -3):

If you like to remove duplicates, just convert to to set:

nodups = set(a)

if you like it in LIST:

nodups = list(set(a))

Comment: He doesnt want to remove duplicates, he wants to remove elements that are in the other list.

Comment: According the result he expecting - this is what he like to do..

Comment: Same result for this particular input, yes, but very different algorithm.

Comment: You could also `return [1, 2, 3]` which gives the same result but doesn't really make much sense.